# DBeaver: how to preconfigure connections for my users?

Tags: dbeaver

I'm trying to pre-configure some connections for my users. The [documentation](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Admin-Manage-Connections/) clearly says that it is possible:

> DBeaver can load multiple connection files. Any files in project folder matching .dbeaver/data-sources*.json pattern will be loaded on startup. So you can create a file, say, .dbeaver/data-sources-2.json in the project folder and DBeaver will see it.

But when I copy a file name `data-sources-padrao.json` to the path `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\.dbeaver\` before starting DBeaver for the first time, no connection is displayed and the file is renamed to `data-sources-padrao.json.bak`. If I copy it after starting DBeaver for the first time, the file is ignored.

**How do I pre-configure a bunch of connections in DBeaver?**

If the user already has a working installation, I'd like to add new connections without disturbing the old ones. If it is a fresh install, the user would open DBeaver and it would show all the connections already configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ops, silly me. My `data-sources-padrao.json` wasn't well formed and was being ignored.

Fixed the '{' and '}' and everything is working fine. I'll leave the question here, maybe will be useful for someone.

DBeaver really considers every file named `data-sources*.json` in the conf dir as a connection file and will display all connections inside.